# type *url.URL has no field or method ParseRequestURI

Tags: go

here's my code:

```
director := func(req *http.Request) {
    fmt.Println(req.URL)

    regex, _ := regexp.Compile(`^/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/(\S+)$`)
    match := regex.FindStringSubmatch(req.URL.Path)
    bucket, filename := match[1], match[2]
    method := "GET"
    expires := time.Now().Add(time.Second * 60)

    signedUrl, err := storage.SignedURL(bucket, filename, &storage.SignedURLOptions{
        GoogleAccessID: user.GoogleAccessID,
        PrivateKey: []byte(user.PrivateKey),
        Method: method,
        Expires: expires,
    })
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println("Error " + err.Error())
    }
    fmt.Println(signedUrl)
    req.URL.ParseRequestURI(signedUrl)
}
```

I want to parse signedUrl to req.URL using ParseRequestURI method
https://golang.org/pkg/net/url/#ParseRequestURI

But when compiling, it throws an error:
`req.URL.ParseRequestURI undefined (type *url.URL has no field or method ParseRequestURI)`

So I tried `req.URL.Parse` and it works.
https://golang.org/pkg/net/url/#Parse

These two functions are close with each other in the documentation.  I can't find any significant difference(s) between them.  So I don't know why one works and the other doesn't.

How can I make `ParseRequestURI` work? And why one works but the other doesn't?

Comment: There is a [Parse function](https://godoc.org/net/url#Parse) and a [Parse method](https://godoc.org/net/url#URL.Parse) on the URL type.  [ParseRequestURI](https://godoc.org/net/url#ParseRequestURI) is a function and can only be called as a function.

Comment: @ThunderCat Thank you.  But how can I know it is a function not method in documentation? As I described above, I can't find difference between `Parse` and `ParseRequestURI ` in the doc.

Comment: The documentation shows a receiver in the signature for methods.

Comment: I think the "`Parse`" I called is `https://golang.org/pkg/net/url/#URL.Parse` accidentally

Comment: I got it, thank you!

Comment: Aside: Compile the regular expression once (outside the director), not for every request; that's slow and wasteful. Use [MustCompile](https://golang.org/pkg/regexp/#MustCompile) if you don't want to handle the error.

Comment: @Peter Thank you for your suggestion!

Answer (score 0):

As you mentioned following function call is not working:

```
req.URL.ParseRequestURI(signedUrl)
```

because:

```
func ParseRequestURI(rawurl string) (*URL, error)
```

is defined under `net/url` package as a package level function [(reference)](http://func%20ParseRequestURI(rawurl%20string)%20(*URL,%20error)), thus cannot be called using a `type`. Though the correct way to call it as below:

```
url.ParseRequestURI(signedUrl) // Here 'url' is from package name i.e. 'net/url'
```

On the other hand, as you mentioned you are successfully able to call `req.URL.Parse` because `Parse` is defined both at `package` level i.e. at 'net/url' [(reference)](https://golang.org/pkg/net/url/#Parse) as well as at `type` level for type `*URL` [(reference)](https://golang.org/pkg/net/url/#URL.Parse).

`Parse` at package `net/url` is defined as:

```
func Parse(rawurl string) (*URL, error)
```

> Parse parses rawurl into a URL structure.
>
> The rawurl may be relative (a path, without a host) or absolute
>   (starting with a scheme). Trying to parse a hostname and path without
>   a scheme is invalid but may not necessarily return an error, due to
>   parsing ambiguities.

`Parse` for the type `*URL` is defined as:

```
func (u *URL) Parse(ref string) (*URL, error)
```

> Parse parses a URL in the context of the receiver. The provided URL
>   may be relative or absolute. Parse returns nil, err on parse failure,
>   otherwise its return value is the same as ResolveReference.

I hope this helps you.